# Place TD elements next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have this small (maybe simple) question. I have a table right now which is displayed as a normal table.

```
------------------- 
| item 1 | item 4 |
------------------- 
| item 2 | item 5 |
------------------- 
| item 3 | item 6 |
-------------------
```

This works fine for most pages (layout wise) but I've got this same table on an other page where the layout of this table doesnt fit the `div` it's in. So I was thinking can I align the table data next to each other, using CSS:

```
------------------------------------------------------- 
| item 1 | item 2 | item 3 | item 4 | item 5 | item 6 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried a couple of things I found using google. 
`display:inline-block;`,`display:inline-table;`,`float:left`. Now IS this at all possible? I know you can do it the other way round, using `display:block`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><i class='fa fa-users' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
        <td><p>". chop($str,"-999") . "</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
        <td><p>" . $row["Tijdsduur"] . "</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><i class='fa fa-euro' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
        <td><p><small>" . $var . "</small></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried a couple of things I found using google.  display:inline-block;

And that will do it.

```css
td { border: solid black 1px; }
tr, td { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><i class='fa fa-users' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
    <td>
      <p>". chop($str,"-999") . "</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
    <td>
      <p>" . $row["Tijdsduur"] . "</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i class='fa fa-euro' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
    <td>
      <p><small>" . $var . "</small></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Right, told you it was probably very simple. Strange that the `inline-block` first didn't work. I don't know what happened. But thanks!